# Building a histogram from MongoDB with Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, histogram, pymongo

I'm trying to create a histogram of MongoDB documents in the following format:

```
{
    "_id":1
    "Properties":[
    {
        "type": "a"
    },
    {
        "type": "d"
    }
    ]
}

{
    "_id":2
    "Properties":[
    {
        "type": "c"
    },
    {
        "type": "a"
    }
    ]
}

{
    "_id":3
    "Properties":[
    {
        "type": "c"
    },
    {
        "type": "d"
    }
    ]
}
```

The output in this example should be:

a = 2

c = 2

d = 2

My workaround at the moment includes querying the entire collection with:

```
collection.find({})
```

And afterwards traversing and accumulating the data with a python dictionary.
I'm sure that there's a better way to do this in the MongoDB query itself, can I achieve this data in a single query as I suspect?

Note that I don't know which "types" I may find before the query is performed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can use MongoDB `aggregation`.

More about `Aggregation`: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind : "$Properties" }, 
    { $group: { _id: "$Properties.type", count: { $sum: 1 } } }
]);
```

Output:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "c",
            "count" : 2.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "d",
            "count" : 2.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "a",
            "count" : 2.0000000000000000
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

In Python:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = MongoClient().test
    pipeline = [
        { "$unwind" : "$Properties" }, 
        { "$group": { "_id": "$Properties.type", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } }
    ]
    print list(db.collection.aggregate(pipeline))
```

Output:

```
[{u'count': 2, u'_id': u'c'}, {u'count': 2, u'_id': u'd'}, {u'count': 2, u'_id': u'a'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this can fit to your scenario, but you can do them separate by property like:

```
count_a = collection.find({'Properties.type':'a'}).count()
count_b = collection.find({'Properties.type':'b'}).count()
count_c = collection.find({'Properties.type':'c'}).count()
```

If you do not know the type you create a variable that would take different type and can simply do something like:

```
mistery_type = 'assign the misery type in var when you know it'
mistery_type_count = collection.find({'Properties.type': mistery_type}).count()
```

Comment: I'll add it to the question - I don't know which types I may meet before the query is performed.

Comment: This is what you need I suppose

Comment: I have also edited my answer with another example where you can put your type in a variable and be more flexible with the count.

Comment: Sorry fellas but actually @Valijon provided what I was looking for.